# how to use 2 fetch_assoc in one while loop?

Tags: php, mysql

i need list something like this. 
First table is display By using the this code.

```
 <?php
    if (isset($_REQUEST['asign'])) {
        include 'includes/connection.php';

        $sql12= $cid->query("SELECT name FROM user WHERE designation='Technical' AND status='1'");
        $query = "SELECT * FROM allinone WHERE flag=3 ORDER BY id ASC";

        $rs = $cid -> query($query);

        $n = $rs -> num_rows;
        echo "<br /><span style='color:red;'><center>$n records found</center></span>";
        echo "<div id='record'>";
        echo "<table border='1' width='80%' align='center' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' id='unsolTable'>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>ID</th>";
        echo "<th>Ticket Number</th>";
        echo "<th>KOID</th>";
        echo "<th>PROBLEM</th>";
        echo "<th>COMMENT</th>";
        echo "<th>DATE</th>";
        echo "<th>TIME</th>";
        echo "<th>STATUS</th>";
        echo "<th>SOLVED BY</th>";
        echo "<th>Assign</th>";
        echo "<th>Assigned to</th>";
        echo "</tr>";
        while ($row = $rs -> fetch_assoc() ) {

            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['token'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['koid'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['problem'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['comment'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['date'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['time'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['status'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['solvedBy'] . "</td>";
    echo  "<td><a href='assign.php?qType=technical&name=anshul&id=" . $row['id'] . "'>anshul</a>
            <br />
            <a href='assign.php?qType=technical&name=kiran&id=" . $row['id'] . "'>kiran</a>
            <br />
            <a href='assign.php?qType=technical&name=akhilesh&id=" . $row['id'] . "'>akhilesh</a></td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['assTo'] . "-" . $row['assTime'] . "-" . $row['assDate'] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            }
            echo"</table>";
            echo "</div>";
            }
            ?>
```

[image]

On the another side is list on the assign i don't want to write it manually just get from the database how can i do this??

```
$sql= $cid->query("SELECT name FROM user WHERE designation='Technical' AND status='1'");
        while ($row=$sql->fetch_assoc()) {
            $name= $row['name'];
        }
```

this is the another code i want to add in first code.

Comment: You can create proper SQL query and there's no need to use 2 fetch assoc. I can't read much from your code so I won't be able to give you exact solution but you should read about joins/subqueries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing prevents you from executing another SQL query inside you while loop; just replace the `echo...anshul...echo...kiran...` part with another while loop containing the code you already provided.

You just have to make sure that you use different variables, otherwise your `$row` variable is overwritten by the second query. Hence, you can do something like this:

```
// ...
echo "<td>" . $row['solvedBy'] . "</td>";

$resultSetAssignedUsers = $cid->query("SELECT name FROM user WHERE designation = 'Technical' AND status = '1'");
while ($rowAssignedUsers = $resultSetAssignedUsers->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<td><a href='assign.php?qType=technical&name=" . $rowAssignedUsers['name'] . "&id=" . $row['id'] . "'>" . $rowAssignedUsers['name'] . "</a>";
}

echo "<td>" . $row['assTo'] . "-" . $row['assTime'] . "-" . $row['assDate'] . "</td>";
// ...
```